# Do you have to host your assets on the proxy server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-proxy

I need to make an ajax call to an external server. To do this I set up a proxy server.

Do I have to host my assets (index.html, ..) on my proxy server or can I use a 2nd server and let that server connect with the proxy.

I suspect that this again would give a cross domain problem?
What are my general options regarding this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic ways to avoid the same origin policy.

**Have the HTML document and the Ajax resource on the same origin**

In this case the answer is "yes" as far as `index.html` is concerned, and no for everything else.

**Use CORS**

In this case, the proxy must add suitable CORS headers and then the answer is "no".

**Use JSONP**

In this case, the proxy must reexpress the data using the JSONP format and then the answer is "no".